# A random array within some bounds

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, random

I have a an array `params` with errors `e_params` and bounds that the array can be `params_bounds`:

```
params = [0.2, 0.2]
e_params = [0.1, 0.05]
params_bounds = [(0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0)]
```

I want to draw a random Gaussian realisation of `params` as follows:

```
import numpy as np
params_mc = np.random.normal(params, e_params)
```

**Is there any way to make sure that the result `params_mc` is within the upper and lower bounds specified by `params_bounds`?**

Thanks for any help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for a [truncated normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution).
Using [`scipy.stats.truncnorm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html),

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lower, upper = (0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 1.0)
mu, sigma = np.array([0.2, 0.2]), np.array([0.1, 0.05])
X = stats.truncnorm(
    (lower - mu) / sigma, (upper - mu) / sigma, loc=mu, scale=sigma)
data = X.rvs((10000, 2))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(data[:, 0], density=True, alpha=0.5, bins=20)
ax.hist(data[:, 1], density=True, alpha=0.5, bins=20)
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

---

Here's another way to visualize the sample. The code is mainly taken [from the matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/scatter_hist.html):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

lower, upper = (0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 1.0)
mu, sigma = np.array([0.2, 0.2]), np.array([0.1, 0.05])
X = stats.truncnorm(
    (lower - mu) / sigma, (upper - mu) / sigma, loc=mu, scale=sigma)
data = X.rvs((10000, 2))
x, y = data.T

nullfmt = mticker.NullFormatter()         # no labels

# definitions for the axes
left, width = 0.1, 0.65
bottom, height = 0.1, 0.65
bottom_h = left_h = left + width + 0.02

rect_scatter = [left, bottom, width, height]
rect_histx = [left, bottom_h, width, 0.2]
rect_histy = [left_h, bottom, 0.2, height]

# start with a rectangular Figure
plt.figure(1, figsize=(8, 8))

axScatter = plt.axes(rect_scatter)
axHistx = plt.axes(rect_histx)
axHisty = plt.axes(rect_histy)

# no labels
axHistx.xaxis.set_major_formatter(nullfmt)
axHisty.yaxis.set_major_formatter(nullfmt)

# the scatter plot:
axScatter.scatter(x, y)

axScatter.set_xlim((-0.1, 0.7))
axScatter.set_ylim((-0.1, 0.5))

bins = 20
axHistx.hist(x, bins=bins)
axHisty.hist(y, bins=bins, orientation='horizontal')

axHistx.set_xlim(axScatter.get_xlim())
axHisty.set_ylim(axScatter.get_ylim())

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `data` is a sample from a 2D truncated normal.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`numpy.clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) to clip values within given bounds.  First generate arrays of minimums and maximums you need, something like:

```
>>> lower_bound = numpy.asarray(param_bounds)[:, 0]
>>> upper_bound = numpy.asarray(param_bounds)[:, 1]
```

Now clip your result:

```
>>> numpy.clip(params_mc, lower_bound, upper_bound)
```

(Untested code, your mileage may vary)

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick idea, you could us np.clip() to do this pretty easily!

```
params_bounds = [np.clip(params_mc[i], params_bounds[i][0],params_bounds[i][1]) for i in range(len(params_mc))]
```